# Pandas read from remote Postgresql with SSH tunnel and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, ssh, sqlalchemy

I can read from my local psql instance like this:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/db_name')
df = pd.read_sql("select * from table_name;", engine)
```

I have a remote postgresql sever which I successfully accessed with ssh tunneling both in PgAdmin4 and pycharm. I use public key file to login into remote server. Now, my question is how do I access that database with pandas. I tried:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost/db_name')
```

Here, username and password are of remote database. I get `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user`. However, with the same username and password I can access the table in PgAdmin.

From what I read, because of ssh tunneling I have to use `localhost` and not the remote server address, right? In pgAdmin I can see that the server is running. So, my question is how do I read the table from remote postgresql database with ssh tunneling? In examples I have seen people using different port (different than 5432) but for me the setup only works if I use port 5432. I have disconnected all other servers to avoid the port conflict but I get the same error.

Comment: How are you creating the tunnel?

Comment: In pgAdmin, I created new server, gave `localhost` as hostname under `Connection`, provided remote db username and password there. Finally, under `SSH Tunnel`, I set up ssh tunnel

Answer (score 1):

The tunnel created by pgAdmin4 is intended for its own use.  It does not arrange for it to listen on 5432, it picks some arbitrary high numbered port and doesn't advertise what port that is.  While you can discover what port it is listening on using system tools (like netstat) and then connect to it, you would probably be better served by finding some other way to set up your tunnel.  There are python libraries that can help with that.

As for why you can connect to 5432 at all, clearly there is something listening there which is either PostgreSQL or pretending to be PostgreSQL, but it doesn't seem to be the one you intend.  You can use `netstat -ao` to find the pid for it and then look up based on that.